# trying to create independent modals and post infomation from different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, modal-dialog

I am trying to do a testing of modal outputs and basically, have it where the content that I am pulling from a multitude of arrays fits in the order of the modals that are being outputted which is the same amount of information that the array info is pulling.

But when I pull the info into the modal it for some reason is just pulling the last array item that I am calling for ALL the modals instead of it being independent.

here is my JS code

```
                    function showModal() {

                        const modalValues = document.querySelectorAll('#modal');

                            for (a = 0; a < modalValues.length; a ++) {

                                    modalValues[a].classList.remove('hide');

                                }
                    }

                    const arrayOne = {
                        firstName: 'John',
                        Speciality: 'Weldind'
                    }

                    const arrayTwo = {
                        firstName: 'Jack',
                        Speciality: 'Uber'
                    }

                    const arrayThree = {
                        firstName: 'Jill',
                        Speciality: 'Nanny'
                    }

                    const arrayFour = {
                        firstName: 'Mill',
                        Speciality: 'Doctor'
                    }


                    const arrayAlls = [arrayOne , arrayTwo, arrayThree, arrayFour];

                    //value and valueTwo id 

                    const valueName =  document.querySelectorAll('#value');

                    for (j = 0; j < valueName.length; j++) {

                        const valueNameArray = [];

                        valueNameArray.push(valueName[j].textContent);

                        const firstName = arrayAlls[j].firstName;
                        valueName[j].textContent = firstName;



                    }




                const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('#modalBtn');

                for (s = 0; s < modalBtn.length; s++) {
                    modalBtn[s].addEventListener('click' , showModal)
                }
```